# QGIS Plugin QuickMapServices error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

The plugin installs fine but fails to load with the following Python error

```
cannot import name QgsImageOperation
```

Comment: what version of QGIS are you using, and on which platform (Windows/Linux/Mac)? You'll need at least QGIS 2.7 (when this class was added).

Comment: @StevenKay Running 2.4 on Ubuntu, unfortunately.
Thanks!