# QuickMap Services plugin for QGIS corrupted

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, quickmapservices

I probably need to use QuickMapServices plugin but when I try to install it I receive thi error message:

[image: Plugin corrupted]

I use QGIS 2.6.1 on windows 10 64bit

I am not the admin of the PC so I am not able to update to newset version of QGIS. The [plugin page](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) shows that the minimun version is 2.4.0

Comment: It Seems to be an error on the plugin page...

Answer (score 4):

related [QGIS Plugin QuickMapServices error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174990/qgis-plugin-quickmapservices-error)

Try to update to QGIS 2.7 or more (QGIS 2.18 is the actual LTR)

QgsImageOperation is a class from qgis.core which is available since QGIS 2.7.

Comment: 2.14. is the "old" LTR according to the website 2.18. is/will be the new LTR :)

Comment: You're right, i edit my answer. But on the download page it's still 2.14 LTR and 2.18 last version. https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: ah, you're right. I was referring to the main page :)

Comment: Yep, it seems that there is an incoherence between the two pages...

Comment: You can use NextGIS QGIS - no need admin rights (if you select install path with write permissions for your user). http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/ QMS Plugin is installed by default and works.